# What Activities can I solo in WvW?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I enjoy the WvW combat, but sometimes I can only get on for an hour or less.

What WvW activities can be soloed and still help the realm's standing?

Comment: Just curious, which server are you on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There may not be much you can do that will *directly* affect your realm's score, but you can certainly help put your team in a better position by disrupting enemy supply lines. Supply is absolutely vital with respect to upgrading your realm's towers and keeps, and denying the enemy team their own supply makes their larger structures easier to capture.

Most classes and builds should be able to flip un-upgraded [supply camps](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Resource_camp) without much trouble. You can also deny the enemy team by taking out their [caravans](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Supply_caravan). An unescorted Pack Dolyak is easy pickings for a solo player, and with the right build you might even be able to deal with upgraded caravans (which are escorted by two veteran guards). The challenge, of course, will be doing so before reinforcements arrive. Taking down a caravan will award you 3 points, but the real benefit is stopping the supply it carries from making it to a keep or tower.

The sentries located at crossroads and choke points can also be easily soloed. Capturing these points will grant you some WvW experience and give your team a single point. (It also removes a speed bump for a friendly zerg. Zerglings *love* standing in glowing rings.)

Comment: Thanks @Brant! It sounds like un-upgraded supply camps are the best way to both solo and best help the cause. The caravans and sentries also sound like good solo targets for some WvW experience even if they aren't game-changers in the war against other realms.

Comment: You are wrong about capturing sentries providing no benefit: http://i.imgur.com/HnyWPyV.jpg Each doly is worth 3, and each sentry is worth 1. Otherwise a good post. Benjamin, note also that if you want to take down a camp, try to do it closer to the 0:00 mark, because if it's flipped before the tick, you don't get the points for it. And if you're wealthy-ish and no one's around, upgrade the camp with dolyak guards before you run off.

Comment: @VaelVictus Huh, I didn't know that, thanks! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Good answer. I also suggest scouting, building defensive siege, refreshing existing siege, escorting supply caravans, tapping enemy keeps to disable their waypoints and distract them, and helping other groups from your own world.