# How can a roamer make a difference?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am interested in separating from the zerg and becoming a roamer in World vs. World. However, I don't want to become useless to my world or become a nuisance to the commanders.

What kinds of responsibilities are roamers expected to fill and what does a roamer need to do to be a productive part of their world's victory in WvW?

Comment: Check out this question, especially my comment on the answer.

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170374/what-activities-can-i-solo-in-wvw/170382#comment230968_170382

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things come to mind:

- **Explore**. Help the zerg (mostly the commanders) by going around and exploring the area for enemies. Often it will be of your interest to make sure that they don't notice you watching them, so that you can sneak after them and look at what they're doing, and what their plans might be. Communicate this information to your own side's commanders.
- **Kill explorers**. This one is simple. Your opponents might have explorers too, so it can be useful to kill those, making their progress slower.
- **Kill mesmers**. Mesmers are often used to create portals and warp large groups around, so it can be quite useful to hunt them down and kill them. This is an opportunity that does not occur very often though.
- **Kill other roamers**. Even if those other roamers are just roaming uselessly, who can be against a bit of pointless fun?
- **Capture camps**. With the right build, you should be able to capture camps all by yourself. (**Note:** This can be very useful to confuse your opponents. Instead of sending out explorers, people often try to locate the opponent's zerg groups by monitoring which locations are being captured. If you can trick them into thinking that *you are a zerg group*, they might end up wasting time on trying to track you down.)
- **Escort dolyaks**: Even though you won't stand a chance against enemy zerg groups this way, sometimes it can be useful to follow a pack dolyak and try to make sure it reaches its destination safely.
- **Kill enemy dolyaks**: Self explanatory. These objectives are often very easy (as not many people choose to escort dolyaks), and your map always shows where they are at any given moment.